# Way to determine gas without deploying to blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, evm

Are there any nifty ways to determine what a smart contract call would need gas without actually deploying the contract to test net?

Can I write solidity code -> compile it -> send runtime bytecode to EVM with constructor -> call specific function and get trace of gas used?

Ideally the EVM would have mainnet's state, so that I can call other contracts on my code. I can do this with geth already, but I can't get the gas.

Thanks